# initialize dictionary with enum, name does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, dictionary, enums, initialization

I'm trying to create a dictionary using a string for the key and enum for the value.  Code:

```
private enum Continent { Africa, Antarctica, Asia, Australia, Europe, NorthAmerica, SouthAmerica }

static void DemoDictionary()
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n\nDictionary Demo: (rivers)");
    Console.WriteLine("=========================\n");
    Dictionary<string, Continent> rivers = new Dictionary<string, Continent>()
    {
        {"Nile", Africa},
        {"Amazon", SouthAmerica},
        {"Danube", Europe}
    };
}
```

All of the Continent names are showing `the name does not exist in the current context` , and I'm not sure why.  The private enum and the static Dictionary method need to stay put, so I need to work around that.

Answer (score 5):

You should use this:

```
Continent.Africa
```

instead of using this

```
Africa
```

This is happening, because the value of each key value pair item of your dictionary is of type `Continent`. If `Africa` was a variable, in which you had assigned the value of Continent.Africa everything would have been ok. Actually, the error message informs you that there isn't any variable called `Africa` in your context, let alone the issue of the type.

That being said, you should change your code to the following one:

```
 Dictionary<string, Continent> rivers = new Dictionary<string, Continent>()
 {
     {"Nile", Continent.Africa},
     {"Amazon", Continent.SouthAmerica},
     {"Danube", Continent.Europe}
 };
```

Comment: @user3066571 You shouldn't say so. I am glad that I helped.